# radio button directive not binding the ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am trying to create a generic radioButton directive which will take options from controller for display:

```
<cs-radio-field options="gender" ng-model="genderValue"></cs-radio-field>
```

and the options would be like

```
$scope.gender = { label: "Gender", required:true,  valueList: [{ text: "Male", value: "yes" },{text:"Female", value:"no"}] };
```

the directive is defined as:

```
app.directive("csRadioField", function () {
    var templateHtml = function () {
        return '<div ng-form="myform">' +
                '<div class="control-group" class="{{options.class}}">' +
                    '<div class="control-label">{{options.label || "Radio"}} {{ options.required ? "*" : ""}} </div>' +
                    '<div class="controls">' +
                        '<div class="radio" ng-repeat="(key, option) in options.valueList">' +
                            '<label> <input type="radio" name="myfield" ng-value="option.value" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="options.required" />{{option.text}} </label>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="field-validation-error" data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$invalid && myform.myfield.$dirty"> ' +
                            '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.required">{{options.label}} is required!!!</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    };

    return {
        scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=' },
        required: ['ngModel', '^form'],
        restrict: 'E',
        template: templateHtml,
    };
});
```

but the ngModel is not binding in the parent scope.. mostly because of new scopes being created by ng-repeat.

how to solve this issue?

the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/myS5hXwxjoDEqQI2q5Q7?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
ng-model="$parent.ngModel"
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqpIPgD5lOUaVYAnCIKm?p=preview)

You're correct that `ng-repeat` creates **child scopes**. You're actually binding to child scopes' property.

Comment: perfect, its working.. and i understand that its assigning to parent scope... but in case i use this directive inside other directives - will that create a problem??

Comment: @HarishR: there should be no problem, the $parent here is your `current` directive's scope.